# Autocomplete options for certain command in ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

I am running Ubuntu 18.04, and do most of my code editing using VisualStudio Code. To open a file from the terminal, I run the command

```
code fileName.java
```

Once I have compiled the java code, there is also the associated .class file in the directory. This means that next time I open the file, and try to autocomplete the command using "Tab", it will autocomplete to

```
code fileName.
```

Would you please be able to show me how to change the options for the `code` command, so that when I type

```
code f
```

and then press Tab, it will autocomplete to

```
code fileName.java
```

rather than just

```
code fileName.
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166885/70524

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this into your `.bashrc`:

```
complete -f -X '!*.java' code
```

and `source ~/.bashrc` it once.

- The `-f` will do completion on **f**iles only.
- The `-X pattern` allows to define a custom *pattern*
- This custom [auto-completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) will happen for your `code` command only and any completion not matching the *pattern* is removed from the completion list.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve the problem is to create bash completion script.

Create new bash completion script with name `java` using your favorite text editor, let it be nano editor for instance:

`user@pc:~$ sudo nano /etc/bash_completion.d/java`

Insert the code into the script:

```
_code()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  local IFS=$'\n'
  COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -f -X '!*.java' -- $cur ) )
}

complete -o filenames -F _code code
```

Save changes and close text editor.

Finally reload bash completion rules - pay attention to 'dot' and following space before first slash:

```
user@pc:~$ . /etc/bash_completion
```

This solution has 2 advantages:

1. The script works system wide.
2. It supports spaces in names of files.